# Disable font Scaling on Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to figure out how to disable Font scaling inside Flutter application. The reason is layout that has to stay more or less the same, no matter if Scaling is enabled on Android device in system settings.

**Reason / Problem:**

Some brands (Xiaomi) would have Scaling enabled by default which leads to larger font sizes inside the app. Depending on layout, it breaks apart.

**Legacy:**

Flutter had this "textScaleFactor" which is now Depricated and will be removed soon.
Normal usecase would be:

```dart
MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
double textScaleFactor = mediaQuery.textScaleFactor;
print('Text scale factor: $textScaleFactor');
```

**Solution:**

I have came up with not ideal solution and does not apply to Global scope but every individual text widget.

```dart
double getScaledFontSize(double baseFontSize, cont) {
  final scaledFontSize = MediaQuery.textScalerOf(cont).scale(1.0);
  return baseFontSize / scaledFontSize;
}
//.... use in widget

Text(
  "This is example",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: "Popins",
    fontSize: getScaledFontSize(24.0, context),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Now I've came across suggestion which will be deprecated and I wonder is there a way to apply something that I have above but on global scope, such as:

NOTE: example below is using **textScaleFactor** which will be removed and I haven't found actual replacement for it.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

Does anyone have suggestions on ways to tacke this?

Comment: Please don't block font scaling induced by the operating system.  People with disabilities NEED that.  Please don't make their lives miserable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information on how to change the deprecated use of `textScaleFactor` to `textScaler` can be found here : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/deprecate-textscalefactor

According to this doc, you can change your code :

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

To this code :

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

Or even simpler,

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery.withNoTextScaling(
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I've missed `TextScaler.noScaling` - "noScaling" and docs does not have it. Docs is a bit missleading. Thank you this works very well.